# How to Reposition Images in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, string-interpolation

Good day Community,

I'm building a platform using Angular 9, whereby users can upload images and it will be viewed in their profile page.
I would like when a user uploads a new image, the image becomes the first image on the list instead of the image becoming the last on the list. Please how can i achieve this?

image.component.html

```
<div class="colorlib-gallery silli">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-pb-md">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-6 no-gutters video"  *ngFor="let fileUpload of fileUploads">
                        <a href="{{fileUpload?.url}}" class="image-popup-link animate-box"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{fileUpload?.url}}" alt="img" style="padding: 10px; ">
                            <div class="desc text-center">
                                
                                <p class="category"><span></span></p>
                            </div>
                        </a>                   
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
    </div>
```

Be awaiting response.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using fileUploads.push function (such as `fileUploads.push(file)`) for adding new file to fileUploads array.
Just use unshift function instead push.

For example; `fileUploads.unshift(file);`